# BitBlt copies only part of data in certain conditions

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, bitblt

This is a strange problem, I've read documentation for BitBlt function and it works without any problems for most of cases, but starts to fail (only part or even none is copied) if I try to copy data from source rectangle with offset much bigger than the size of destination... strange?? Here are few samples:

This is code that I use, and the result is dependant on the parameters I pass.
The bitmap has a width of `m_iTileAreaWidth + 2 * m_iTileAreaMargin` and a height of `m_iTileAreaHeight + 2 * m_iTileAreaMargin`

```
BOOL bBltOk = ::BitBlt(_hdcDest, 0, 0, m_iTileAreaWidth, m_iTileAreaHeight,
                       hdcSource, m_iTileAreaMargin, m_iTileAreaMargin, SRCCOPY);
```

If `m_iTileAreaMargin` is **600** and `m_iTileAreaWidth` and `m_iTileAreaHeight` are both **200** then **130px** of source area is copied

If `m_iTileAreaMargin` is **500** and `m_iTileAreaWidth` and `m_iTileAreaHeight` are both **200** then **full** source are is copied

If `m_iTileAreaMargin` is **800** and `m_iTileAreaWidth` and `m_iTileAreaHeight` are both **200** then **none** source area is copied

Well, I'm sure that whole area is generated - when I use this code:

```
bBltOk = ::BitBlt(_hdcDest, 0, 0, rcScreen.Widht(), rcScreen.Height(),
                  _hdcSource, 0, 0,SRCCOPY);
```

Then I see whole area generated

Does anyone have any idea why I have such problems with such simple function?

Comment: And how big is your source bitmap?

Comment: source bitmap is 1400x1400 (or bigger) depending on mentioned parameters (width/height) so enough to store all required data...

Comment: I think you need to post your bitmap creation code. Maybe you have a clipping region set up on the source context or something?

Comment: there is no clipping region afair, but there are some strange things happening maybe You might be familiar, or point me where to search for solution: when I copy whole source region I get valid data even in central part, but if I try copy only central part (using computed dx, dy) only part of it is copied. I don't have access to whole bitmap/hdc creation of source, only my dest I have full access to.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved - yet some mistery remains. Problem was that source bitmap (or hdc, don't have access to some of internals) was not configured to hold all required data (size too small).

Mistery is that I was able to copy whole area and get valid data, but when tried to copy only some parts (even one that was already in whole area) I got empty data.